# Grok email and IP in mixed content line

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to Grok two different fields such as the email addresses and the IP.

I am doing the following:

```
 grok {match => [ "message", "%{EMAILADDRESS:username_client}" %{IP:client_ip} ]}
```

The first bit is fine however the

> %{IP:client_ip}

is wrong. The "message" is basically mixed such as:
`Whatever whatever 200 300 100 example@example.com whatever whatever IP` (or something similar)

Comment: Try `"%{EMAILADDRESS:username_client}.*%{IP:client_ip}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify *any 0 or more characters* pattern with `.*` (greedy version, use if the IP is at the end of the line) or `.*?` (lazy version, use if there are few chars between the email and IP) and put it in between the 2 grok patterns:

```
"%{EMAILADDRESS:username_client}.*%{IP:client_ip}"
                                ^^
```